# How to tell if you are logged in through AD or Local

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I'm writing an application in C# and I need to be able to determine if the user has logged on to an Active Directory account or to a local account.  Any idea how to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is call:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity i = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Once you get the [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can read the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the domain name.  Then you can check domain name against the expected domain name.